# systemd-activate socket activation for UDP daemons

Tags: sockets, datagram, systemd

I like using `systemd-activate(8)` for **testing** socket-activated daemons during development,
however, it seems it only listens for TCP connections:

```
% /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-activate -l 5700 ./prog
Listening on [::]:5700 as 3.

% netstat -nl |grep 5700
tcp6       0      0 :::5700             :::*             LISTEN
```

I am using a program that handles datagrams (UDP).  How can I make `systemd-activate` listen on a UDP port?  Or is there a 
simple way to do this using other tools, without going to the trouble of crafting and installing a systemd unit file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple C program to do this; code below (public domain).

The usage is:

```
./a.out <port-number> <prog> [<arg1> ...]
```

The program opens a UDP socket on `<port-number>`, sets the environment variables that systemd socket-activated daemons expect, then executes `<prog>` with whatever arguments follow.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("no port specified\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("no program specified\n");
        return -1;
    }

    uint16_t port = htons((uint16_t) strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10));
    if (port == 0 || errno) {
        printf("failed to parse port: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    /* create datagram socket */
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("failed to open socket; errno: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = port;
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    /* bind socket to port */
    int r = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (r < 0) {
        printf("bind failed; errno: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    /* execute subprocess */
    setenv("LISTEN_FDS", "1", 0);
    execvp(argv[2], argv + 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was recently added to `systemd-activate`: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/2411, and will be part of systemd-229 when it is released.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a way to do it with `systemd-activate`.

You may want to employ some `.service` unit file and a `.socket` unit file with dependencies. In a `.socket` unit you will describe `ListenDatagram=` option. See [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html#ListenStream=) for more details.